# Spark SQL query issue - SQL with Subquery doesn't seem to retrieve records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL query like:

```
Select * from xTable a Where Exist (filter subquery) AND (a.date IN (Select max(b.date) from xTable b))
```

Under certain circumstances (when a filter table is not provided) , my `filter subquery` should simply do a `Select 1`.

Whenever I run this in Impala it returns records, in Hive it complains that only 1 subquery expression is allowed. However, when I run it as a Spark SQL in Spark 2.4, it returns an empty dataframe. Any idea why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify _my `filter subquery` should simply do a Select 1._ Does it?

Comment: Yes, it needs to do just a "Select 1" if no filter table is provided, however if a filter table is provided , then do a Select * from filtertable.

Comment: Since query by itself looks okay, it means there is not enough info to find out whats wrong. Can you add `explain()` output, and check executor logs for any exceptions)?

Comment: Also, I would change `a.date IN (Select max(b.date) from xTable b)` to `a.date = (Select max(b.date) from xTable b)`, because its join vs. filter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the reason. It is not related to the query. It seems like an issue while trying to create a table using a csv file in Hive.

When you select the source - path to the csv file in HDFS
, and then under the format -  check the  'Has Header' check box.

It seems to create the table ok.

Then, When I execute the following in Hive or Impala :

`Select max(date) from xTable`

I get the max date back (Where the date column is a String)

However, when I try and run the same via Spark SQL:

I get the result  as  `date`  (The same name as the column header).

If I remove the header from CSV file and import it, and them manually create the headers and types, then I am not facing this issue.

Seems like some form of bug or may be a user error from my end.